# Prove that the problem has at most one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Prove that the initial and boundary problem $$\\u_t(x,t)-u_{xxx}(x,t)=0,0<x<1,t>0 \\
u(x,0)=\phi(x),0<x<1 \\
u_x(0,t)=h(t),t>0 \\
u_{xx}(0,t)=H(t), t>0 \\
u_x(1,t)=g(t),t>0$$

has at most one solution.

Hint: Use the function $$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 u_x^2(x,t)dx$$

I have done the following:

We consider the function $E(t)=\int_0^1 u_x^2(x,t)dx$.

$$E'(t)=\int_0^1 2u_x(x,t)u_{xt}(x,t)dx=\int_0^1 2u_x(x,t)(u_t(x,t))_x dx \\ =\left[2u_x(x,t)u_t(x,t)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 2u_{xx}(x,t)u_t(x,t)dx \\=2u_x(1,t)u_t(1,t)-2u_x(0,t)u_t(0,t)-\int_0^1 2u_{xx}(x,t)u_{xxx}(x,t)dx\\= -\int_0^1 (u_{xx}^2)_x dx=-u_{xx}^2(1,t) \leq 0$$

So $E(t)$ is decreasing.

$E(0)=\int_0^1 u_x^2(x,0)dx=0$ because $u(x,0)=0 \Rightarrow u_x(x,0)=0$.

$t \geq 0 \Rightarrow E(t) \leq 0 \Rightarrow E(t) \leq 0$

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
E(t)\leq 0\\ 
E(t) \geq 0
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow E(t)=0 \Rightarrow u_x^2(x,t)=0 \Rightarrow u_x(x,t)=0 $$

We would know that the solution is unique when $u(x,t)=u(x_0,t), 0<x_0<1$.

How could we show this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose there are two solutions $v, w.$  then $u = v - w$ satisfies the equations with all $\phi, h, H$ and $g$ set to zero. now look at $$E = \int_0^1 u_x^2 \,dx $$ you have shown that $$E = 0 $$ that means $ u_x = const \to u = f(t).$ now use $u_t - u_{xxx} = 0$ to show that $f(t) = constant.$ finally, $u(x,0) = 0$ gives you $$u \equiv 0. $$

Comment: Isn't it as followed?? $$E=0 \Rightarrow u_x^2=0 \Rightarrow u_x=0 \Rightarrow u(x,t)=f(t)$$

Comment: that is right. use the boundary conditions to show in fact that $u = 0.$

Comment: Which of the condtions should I use?? I got stuck right now... @abel

Comment: if you use $u_t - u_{xxx} = 0$ with $u = f(t)$ you get $f'(t) = 0$ implies $f$ is constant. and $u(x,0) = 0$ makes the constant zero. that is it.

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-) @abel